# Fixed end moments

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

[image]

If B is a roller or pinned, should the fixed end moment for AB be (wl<sup>2</sup>)/8?

Comment: No. The moment distribution method requires calculating the "fixed end moment" ASSUMING both ends are FIXED.

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: Note my comment is pertaining to the continuous structure shown only, which will have a FEM of + wL1/12^2 to the left of support B, and - Pab^2/L2^2 to the right of B. Then the distribution will be performed on the net moment at B when inlocked. If beam A-B is a single span beam with support A fixed and B simply supported, then the FEM at A equals to -wL^2/8, and FEM = 0 at support B.